# JSON request does not give anything

Tags: android, json

I have a bug in the code, but I can not find it. I have to read the message and the code from the JSON request below.

```
try {
    Log.d("qwertz", json);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
    JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String code = JO.getString("code");
    String message = JO.getString("message");
    if (code.equals("win"))
    {
        showDialog("Du hast etwas gewonnen", message,code);
    }
    else if (code.equals("false"))
    {
        showDialog("Du hast leider nichts gewonnen", message,code);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That is a JSON example

```
{
    "server_response": {
        "code": "win",
        "message": "Du hast einen PzKpfw S35 739(f) gewonnen"
    }
}
```

Comment: `server_response` is not an array.

Comment: how do I have to change the code to read code or message

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you not to process json directly by yourself, instead you can use many libraries that will do the job for you. To mention you can use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) or [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

If you still want to correct your code you can try this:

```
JSONObject response = jsonObject.getJsonObject("server_response");
String code = response.getString("code");
```

Comment: Thank youe very much! I was blind :D